# Can I use Restangular.extendModel or extendCollection with a nested resource route?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Is it possible to use extendModel or extendCollection with a nested route?

e.g.,

`http://myserver.com/topresources/nestedresources`

`Restangular.extendModel('topresources/nestedresources',function(model){ ... })`

There's a [github issue](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/736) which references using `Restangular.setOnElemRestangularized` with a nested resource by manually handling the nested route... but I would prefer to stick to the normal extendModel/extendCollection methods.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is: No, you cannot use `.extendModel()` on a nested resource.

You have given the answer to your question yourself and this seems to be more like a feature request than a concrete question and belongs to the Github issues of Restangular.